# Dynamically adding and removing element from HTML DOM

Tags: jquery, html, dom, tabs

I am working on an HTML page where there are a list of items in a table and on clicking an item a new tab is generated showing the details of the item clicked. I am using jquery-ui tabs for dynamically creating tabs. I need to open a tab for an item only if a tab does not exist for that item. I use the below code to achieve this

```
if(! $('#selector').length )
{
   //create new tab for the item
}
```

I use tabs with unique id for each item. This code works when loading tab for the first time, the problem is I also have a X button to close the tab and on click f that button I remove the tab division from HTML DOM using jquery .remove() function. This way the tab gets removed but when I try to add the tab for a particular item after removing it once. Then the above code doesn't work it shows that tab already exist. And new tab is not getting created. How can I remove an element completely from HTML DOM so that the above code works for recreating tabs after removing it once. Thanks in advance for any help

```
<body>
    <div id='tabs'>

        <ul>

        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

        $("#tabs").tabs();

        $(document).on('click', '.clickable_sellername', function(){

            debugger;
            var sellerid = parseInt(this.id.split('_')[2]);
            var sellername = $(this).text();

            if($('#tabindex_'+sellerid).length == 0){

                $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url :"/myadmin/loadprofile",
                    data:{ 'sellerid':sellerid },
                    dataType:"html",
                    success: function(data){

                        // Add a new tab
                        $("#tabs ul").append("<li id='tabindex_"+sellerid+"' ><a href='#sellertab_" + sellerid + "'>" +  sellername + "</a><a href='#' id='close_"+sellerid + "' class='ui-tabs-anchor remove' role='presentation' >x</a></li>");

                        // Add content to the newly added tab
                        $("#tabs").append("<div id='sellertab_"+sellerid+"' ></div>");
                        $('#sellertab_'+sellerid).html(data)

                        // Refresh tabs to add newley added tab
                        $("#tabs").tabs("refresh");

                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){

            // Get the tab number of pressed close button
            var sellerid = parseInt(this.id.split("_")[1]);

            // Remove the tabindex
            $('#tabindex_'+sellerid).remove();

            // Remove the tab content
            $('#sellertab_'+sellerid).remove();

            //Refresh the tabs
            $('#tabs').tabs("refresh");

        });

    });
```

Comment: Please post your code - it's much easier for us to understand what you're doing from that. Also, from your description it sounds like you should be using delegated event handlers.

Comment: please add your `html` structure...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selector').length
```

returns a non zero value for an "list" element even after removing the
it from the DOM using jquery  .remove()  whereas in case of a "div" element
it returns zero for the above expression after removing the div using .remove(). So I used "div" element for checking purpose ie now i use

```
if($('#sellertab_'+sellerid).length == 0)
```

instead of

```
if($('#tabindex_'+sellerid).length == 0)
```